# jQuery When Done on dynamically pulled function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred

I have the following code:

In site-code.js

....

```
var ajaxContentFunc = $(origin).data("modal-content-handler");

$.when(window[ajaxContentFunc]()).done(function (resp) {
    kModal.showContent(resp);
});
```

In another file I have the following  tag and function

```
<a href="#" data-modal-content-handler="ajaxContentGeneration">Click Me</a>
```

....

```
function ajaxContentGeneration() {

    var aProm = $.ajax({

        url: "tests/ajax/AjaxTest.aspx",
        data: { exampleType: "modal-ajax" },
        dataType: "html"


    });


    aProm.done(function (data) {

        console.log("Ajax Loaded!");
        var content = $(data).find("#ajax-content");

        return aProm;

    });


}
```

I need to populate the result of the ajaxContentGeneration (whatever method that might be) into the variable to send to showContent or in other words:

1) Pull the **ajaxContentFunction** Name from the  tag's modal-content-handler data attribute

2) Call function (in this case ajaxContentGeneration)

3) Wait for the function's ajax to complete and return the data generated (in this case html)

4) When completed pass that value to kModal.showContent(----Here----);

However currently I am getting:

1) Pulls ajaxContentFunctionName correctly

2) Calls Function (ajaxContentGeneration() function)

3) Calls kModal.showContent(undefined). This is called prematurely because the deferred isn't correctly waiting for the function call to complete (after the ajax is done).

4) Ajax Completes

Where am I messing up here ?

Comment: what a mess... seems like some stuff are missing in your explanation. what is `(2) call function`. what function? where is this function `ajaxContentFunctionName` ? I am skeptical somebody could help..

Comment: Sorry I was removing a whole bunch of extraneous stuff here and accidently renamed the requirement in the steps, so you are right it is a mess. I have adjusted to (hopefully) offer some more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you are 95% there.

Use `.then()` instead of `.done()` and return the promise returned by `$.ajax().then()` :

```
function ajaxContentGeneration() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "tests/ajax/AjaxTest.aspx",
        data: { exampleType: "modal-ajax" },
        dataType: "html"
    }).then(function (data) {
        return $(data).find("#ajax-content"); // this will return jQuery
        // return $(data).find("#ajax-content").html(); // this will return html
    });
}
```

You can probably also purge `$.when()` from the top-level call :

```
var ajaxContentFunc = $(origin).data("modal-content-handler");
window[ajaxContentFunc]().then(function (resp) {
    // `resp` is whatever was returned by the `return $(data).find()...` statement above
    kModal.showContent(resp);
});
```

The reason I say "probably" is that `$.when()` would be necessary if value-returning (not promise-returning) functions could be called instead of `ajaxContentGeneration()`.

Comment: why `then` instead of `done` ? I think that has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I knew I was close, but as it always is, that last 5% is the one that makes you bash your head against your desk. Thank you.

Comment: @vsync, jQuery's `.then()` and `.done()` are (generally) not interchangeable. `.then()`  returns a new Promise resolved with whatever its callback returns. `.done()` returns its input Promise unmolested. Here, the OP needs `.then()`.

Comment: no, he should use `done` in this scenario. `then` shouldn't be used unless you want to create a new promise for some reason, which isn't the case here. Using `always` will act like `then`, but also shouldn't be used. `done` must work for HTTP status `200`

Comment: @vsync, think about it. If `.done()` was used, how would the line `return $(data).find("#ajax-content");` contribute to the Promise returned by `ajaxContentGeneration()`? It wouldn't.

Comment: well it's all hose you view things, and what purpose you give to your functions what what future plans and other uses you would have for them.. I gave another answer now to show a different use.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to do:

```
// should really be renamed...
function ajaxContentGeneration(){
    return $.ajax({
        url      : "tests/ajax/AjaxTest.aspx",
        data     : { exampleType: "modal-ajax" },
        dataType : "html"
    })
}
```

#### Somewhere else:

```
var ajaxContentFunc = $(origin).data("modal-content-handler");

window[ajaxContentFunc]()
    .done(function(RES){
        kModal.showContent( $(RES).find("#ajax-content") );
    });
```

So the functionality of the `ajaxContentGeneration` function will be to return an AJAX promise, and not have it manipulated inside it, but do the manipulation where needed (*getting the `#ajax-content` element from the response*)

---

Note that this whole thing is bad practice JS design, and you should avoid having functions on top of the `window` object, but instead on another object.

Comment: The function on window is done because the function name is not known and defined on a page by page basis by the <a> tag's data attribute. This is also why I modify the return html in the function itself because different ajax calls will return different ajax and I want to filter the html before the generic and reusable kModal.showContent method.