# Receiving a deferred object as the result of a function

Tags: jquery, promise

I'm trying to create a globally accessible function that performs an ajax call:

```
function getDataModel(dataModelName = "dm1") {
    // I want to send the deferred object back
    return $.Defered($.get(url + dataModelName, function(r){
        return new DataModel(r)
    })
}

function DataModel(data){
    this.foo = data.foo
    this.bar = data.bar
}
```

I want to send the DataModel object to another function after it's created:

```
console.log("1");

// After the deferred object finishes being built, use it in another function, 
// but that function can't be called till the object is built
$.when(getDataModel(fromSelection)).then(function(data,status,jqXHR){
    console.log("2")
    console.log(data)
    console.log(status)
    console.log(jqXHR)
    init(data)
})

function init(data){
    console.log("3")
    console.log(data)
}
```

And here's the output:

```
> 1
> 2
> undefined
> undefined
> undefined
> 3
> (error because 'data' isn't defined)
```

So obviously, it's performing in the correct order, but I'm not getting the object back. Is this because it's not a jQuery object? If not...

What am I doing wrong here? I've looked at the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/), but it didn't have anything that pertains to this. I also checked a few posts:

1. [jQuery When Done on dynamically pulled function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256548/jquery-when-done-on-dynamically-pulled-function-call). However, this creates the promise object inside the function.
2. [jQuery.when - Callback for when ALL Deferreds are no longer 'unresolved' (either resolved or rejected)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824615/jquery-when-callback-for-when-all-deferreds-are-no-longer-unresolved-either). This is performing the ajax call directly inside the `$.when`, similar to the docs.

But not finding an answer. Also, I realize there is something missing with my understanding of promises, so if someone could shed some light on what I did wrong, that would be a huge help.

Comment: You should neither call `$.Deferred` nor `$.when` here. Try to just drop them.

Comment: What do you expect with the `new DataModel(r)` to happen? You cannot `return` anything from the callback that you pass to`$.get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- The callback function passed to `$.get` cannot be used to return a value that will resolve the Deferred object. Use `then` for this purpose.
- `$.get` returns a Deferred object already, so there is no need to pass it to `$.Deferred()`.
- `$.when` is useful when you have more than one promise to resolve, but as you just have the one returned from your function, you don't need it, and can apply `then` directly on the function's return value.
- There is nothing else passed to the `then` callback than only the promised value, so neither *jqXHR* nor *status* will be available.

Here is the corrected code:

```
function getDataModel(dataModelName = "dm1") {
    return $.get(url + dataModelName).then(function (r) {
        return new DataModel(r);
    });
}
```

and:

```
getDataModel(fromSelection).then(function (data) {
    console.log("2");
    console.log(data);
    init(data);
});
```